# Pixel appearing when using css ul li display-inline block

Tags: css, html-lists, pixel

The image is pretty self explanatory. I can't get rid of those two pixels at the bottom of only one list element. I've inserted text-decoration:none and list-style-type none in every corner of the css with no results.
Reason?

http://s1089.photobucket.com/user/3Joez/media/disp_zps6fe2774c.jpg.html

```
#rightnav {
float:right;
width:65%;
height:50px;
/*border:2px solid #Df1;*/
}

#rightnav ul {
 margin-left:9.5%;
/*border:1px solid #F30;*/
width:500px;

}

#rightnav ul li {

 display:inline-block;
 font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
 font-size:1.4em;
 margin-left:2%;
 margin-top:1.5%;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none ;
 list-style:none; 
 list-style-type:none;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you have an `<a>` inside your `<li>`. Did you change the text decoration on that? Changing it on the `<li>` will probably not change the inner style because the UA CSS likely ties the underline style to the `<a>` tag.

```
#rightnav ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: After hours of searching, that answer is a blessing. Thanks.